# Understanding operand forms

Tags: assembly, x86-64

9(%rax, %rdx): What happens here? Is *9* the offset? and do you add the two registers together?

I'm reading Randal E. Bryant and David R. O'Hallaran's *"Computer Systems - A programmer's Persepctive"*

At page 209 we are presented with a table (Operand forms):

[image]

---

It's then possible to do a little assignment where I have to fill the empty table with values. I tried my best but am stuck as you can see:

[image]

9(%rax, %rdx). Is the *9* the offset? And do you add the two registers here? Not quite sure what to add. I would really appreciate if someone could walk me through the last empty values I need to fill.

---

Below is the solutions:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of AT&T assembly! The 9 in `9(%rax, %rdx)` is commonly called *displacement* or sometimes *base*, and you should indeed just add all three values:

9+rax+rdx = 9+0x100+0x3 = 0x10C

This address is then dereferenced so the value 0x11 is loaded from the address 0x10C.

I would recommend reading the Solaris [x86 Assembly Language Reference Manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28388/ennby.html)  if you plan to stick with AT&T, or just switch to Intel syntax since it's much more widely used (especially in processor documentation).

Comment: Thank you, Igor. Makes sense now!